# Android ViewPager start swipe and stop swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager with swipe options.
How can I detect the swipe start (the moment when transition between view starts) and the swipe end (the moment when transtion betwwen view stops)?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom view pager and override onDrag or onTouch event methods.

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager{

public MyViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {
    return super.onDragEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `OnPageChangeListener`.
The method `onPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)` will inform you about the progress of the page change (either in pixels, or as a float between 0 and 1), so it will be easy to see when it starts and stops.
Heres the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled%28int,%20float,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the OnPageListener interface of the ViewPager class. The interface provide three methods to listen for changes to the ViewPager.

```
 @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
   //Called when the scroll state changes.
   // The state variable that you receive as parameter will help you know the state of the view pager. 
   // The ViewPager can be in any of the three states, 
   // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
   // If the state is SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, it signals that the page is being dragged. A transition to this state can signal a start of drag.
   // If the state is SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, it signals that there is no dragging going on and a possible end of any drags.
   // Keep a variable that changes state as per your requirements.
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, 
    float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
   //This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled, 
   //either as part of a programmatically initiated smooth scroll 
   //or a user initiated touch scroll.
   // The positionOffset parameted returns a float between [0,1) Any number between 0 and 1 indicates that the page is being dragged. 
   // This can be used as an indicator for drag start and end events.
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.

  }};
```

All the best :)

Comment: And onPageScrolled is the one he will be most interested in.

Comment: I think onPageScrollStateChanges will also be able to handle the requirements in an equally easy manner. Any reason why that will be an issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: With onPageScrolled, he'll get the offset (so percentage of the current scroll position) that will be needed if he wants to animate something like moving or fading a view at the exact same speed that the scroll occurs.

Comment: Ya, but the OP wanted only the start and end states.